# ggplot's stat_function() giving wrong result

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, visualization

I generated some data to perfome a regression on it:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nnet)

# Generating the data --------------------------
set.seed(100)
helicopter <- rnorm(20, mean = 35, sd = 3)
car <- rnorm(20, mean = 30, sd = 3)
bus <- rnorm(20, mean = 25, sd = 3)
bike <- rnorm(20, mean = 20, sd = 3)

transportation_data <- data.frame(helicopter, car, bus, bike) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:4, values_to = "income", names_to = "mode")

# Setting up the regression -------------------
transportation_regression <- multinom(mode~income, data = transportation_data)
```

So far, so good. I now want to plot the regression results (probability of choosing a certain mode of transportation based on income) using `stat_function`:

```
ins <- coef(transportation_regression)[1:3]
betas <- coef(transportation_regression)[4:6]

transportation_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = income))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { 1 / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) }, aes(color = "bike"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) }, aes(color = "bus"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) }, aes(color = "car"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x) / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) }, aes(color = "helicopter"))
```

[image: plot1]
I get this output, which is obviously wrong, and a warning `Warning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` where I don't know what it means.

When I use the same functions, but predict data points first, everything works just fine:

```
income <- seq(0,50,0.1)
result <- matrix( , nrow = length(income), ncol = 4)
i <- 1
for(x in income){
  result[i,1] <- 1 / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) # bike
  result[i,2] <- exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) # bus
  result[i,3] <- exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) # car
  result[i,4] <- exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x) / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) # helicopter
  
  i <- i + 1
}

cbind(income, as.data.frame(result)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = V1:V4) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = income, y = value, color = name))+
  geom_line()
```

[image: plot2]

Why don't the `stat_function()` in `ggplot` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a misunderstanding of how the function works.  Here's an example of using `stat_function()` to generate the right result:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(nnet)

# Generating the data --------------------------
set.seed(100)
helicopter <- rnorm(20, mean = 35, sd = 3)
car <- rnorm(20, mean = 30, sd = 3)
bus <- rnorm(20, mean = 25, sd = 3)
bike <- rnorm(20, mean = 20, sd = 3)

transportation_data <- data.frame(helicopter, car, bus, bike) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:4, values_to = "income", names_to = "mode")

# Setting up the regression -------------------
transportation_regression <- multinom(mode~income, data = transportation_data)
#> # weights:  12 (6 variable)
#> initial  value 110.903549 
#> iter  10 value 48.674542
#> iter  20 value 46.980349
#> iter  30 value 46.766625
#> iter  40 value 46.734782
#> iter  50 value 46.732249
#> final  value 46.732163 
#> converged


ins <- coef(transportation_regression)[1:3]
betas <- coef(transportation_regression)[4:6]

transportation_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = income))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { 1 / (1 + exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) + exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) + exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x)) }, aes(color = "bike"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) / (1 + exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) + exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) + exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x)) }, aes(color = "bus"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) / (1 + exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) + exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) + exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x)) }, aes(color = "car"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x) / (1 + exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) + exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) + exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x)) }, aes(color = "helicopter"))
```

[image]

There were a couple of problems originally.  Take, for example, the first instance of `stat_function()`,

```r
stat_function(fun = function(x) { 
         1 / (1 + sum(exp(ins + betas * x))) }, 
     aes(color = "bike"))
```

You're expecting `ins + betas * x` to be equivalent to `ins[1] + betas[1] * x + ins[2] + betas[2] * x + ins[3] + betas[3] * x`, but it isn't essentially recycling `ins` and `betas` to make them vectors as long as `x` and then multiplying `betas` by `x` and adding `ins`.

The other problem was the `sum()` around `exp(ins ...)` Rather than summing the rows, it's summing all rows and columns of the output, making a scalar value.

You could also make it a bit more general using matrix calculations:

```r
b <- coef(transportation_regression)

transportation_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = income))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { 1 / (1 + rowSums(exp(cbind(1, x) %*% t(b)))) }, aes(color = "bike"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[1] + betas[1] * x) / (1 + rowSums(exp(cbind(1, x) %*% t(b)))) }, aes(color = "bus"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[2] + betas[2] * x) / (1 + rowSums(exp(cbind(1, x) %*% t(b)))) }, aes(color = "car"))+
  stat_function(fun = function(x) { exp(ins[3] + betas[3] * x) / (1 + rowSums(exp(cbind(1, x) %*% t(b)))) }, aes(color = "helicopter"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>